# Issues with notification pending intent

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to launch a non cancellable ongoing notification but no matter what I try it is cancellable.

code:

```
    NotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int icon = R.drawable.btn_rating_star_on_pressed_holo_light;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    notification = new Notification(icon, getString(R.string.notificationMSG), when);
    notification.ledARGB = 999;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT + Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR + Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, getString(R.string.app_name), getString(R.string.notificationMSG), contentIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(Global.NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
```

I would also like to know how to make it go away once the activity that launched it is finished. Tried doing the following but it works only some times.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    notificationManager.cancel(Global.NOTIFICATION_ID);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. It's as if none of the flags are actually activated. The LED is not working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

For some stupid reason we cannot put the flags directly in the `PendingIntent` and need to set them this way instead.